# Actions On Google Deployment using webhook

Tags: java, google-app-engine, actions-on-google, google-api-java-client

I am using Java Client Library to use google Dialogflow. My questions is what happens when we use "appEnginedeploy" using gradle? Where is the code stored and more importantly how the implemented database and other files of code stored and accessed by our agent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`appEngineDeploy` is setup to deploy the code to [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine), a computing platform on Google Cloud. Code and associated project files are stored as they are in your project.

It's not entirely a VM, so you shouldn't necessarily think of App Engine as locating filepaths. If the project can make the links locally, then it should behave the same way in App Engine.

With regards to databases, it would depend if you're using an embedded database or using a hosted solution through another Google Cloud service. Presumably you'd use the database APIs for a Cloud service as shown in the documentation.

Comment: I have added few classes which use hibernate framework. Before deploying no error and everything is fine. When I click on appengineDeploy: it gives an error that the package does not exist and then it seems java also fails to recognize it after this.In short its not recognizing(?) the external packages/dependencies I have used.

Comment: I am using maven for all my backend(hibernate). To deploy..as provided on the boilerplate code-gradle.